# Excel Interface implements enumeration

Tags: excel, interface, enumeration, vba

I am working on a class that implements an interface.

I found a road block when I try to implement an enumeration. Is that possible?

Example:

```
IFruits
Public enum enuFruits
End enum
Public Sub AddNewToCollection(ByVal TypeSelected as enuFruits)
End sub

CApple
Implements Ifruits

Private enum enuFruits
End enum
Private Sub IFruits_AddNewToCollection(ByVal TypeSelected as enuFruits)
End sub
```

This code above, does NOT work. An empty enumeration can't be declared.

The idea behind is:
Different implementations would make us of an unique enumeration (different number of items/types). But in the end all of them will implement in in the interface procedure.

This enumeration is a mere help for ease coding. For now I have a procedure that prints out to the inm window so I can quickly choose, but would be cool to have intellisense.

I've tried multiple theories:

- Implementing defined "Type" that contains list of enumerations and then declaring it in the modules.
- Multiple nesting property get/let wishing that at some point magic happens.

I just can't get it around... maybe It can't be done. I want to move on :D

Comment: If classes have different Enumerations, they aren't implementing the same interface. Period.  You can make this "work" by declaring the parameter as `Long`, but it still doesn't resolve  the design problem.

Comment: @Comintern I was thinking it overnight. I believe you are right, I will go with just different classes and forget about the interface. Many thanks for the tip, much appreciated!